# BQ SQL solution solution for comparing rows based on variance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to compare scraped retail item price data in BigQuery (~2-3B rows depending on the time period and retailers included); with the intent to identify meaningful price differences.  For example $1.99 vs $2.00 isn't meaningful, but $1.99 vs $2.50 is meaningful.  Meaningful is quantified as a 2% difference between prices.

Example dataset for one item looks like this:

```
ITEM       Price($)  Meaningful (This is the column I'm trying to flag) 
Apple      $1.99     Y (lowest price would always be flagged)
Apple      $2.00     N ($1.99 v $2.00)
Apple      $2.01     N ($1.99 v $2.01)  Still using $1.99 for comparison
Apple      $2.50     Y ($1.99 v $2.50)  Still using $1.99 for comparison
Apple      $2.56     Y ($2.50 v $2.56)  Now using $2.50 as new comp. price
Apple      $2.62     Y ($2.55 v $2.62)  Now using $2.56 as new comp. price
```

I was hoping to solve the problem just using SQL Window functions (lead, lag, partition over, etc..) comparing the current row's price to the next following row. However, that doesn't work correctly when I get to a non-meaningful price because I always want the next value to be compared to the most recent meaningful price (see $2.50 row example above that's compared to $2.00 and NOT $2.01 in the prior row)

#### My Questions:

- Is it possible to solve this with SQL alone in BigQuery? (e.g. What creative SQL logic solution am I overlooking, like bucketing based on the variance amounts?)
- What programmatic options do I have since I can't use stored procedures with BQ? Python/Dataframes in GCP Datalab? BQ UDFs?

Comment: "For example $1.99 vs $2.00 isn't meaningful, but $1.99 vs $2.50 is meaningful."  Unfortunately, that description might be helpful to you, but it is not meaningful to others.  What is the exact threshold that you care about?  Is it measured in dollar, percents, or some other units?

Comment: Good point, I included it in the table header description as (> 20% Diff) but I'll edit the ask to be more specific.  For me a 20% or greater variance between prices is considered meaningful.

Comment: you should use lag to keep a 'copy' of the 'last meaningful value' in each row - then compare to that

Comment: The meaningful flag column doesn't actually exist in the data yet, that's essentially what I'm trying to calculate with SQL.  I tried using LAG originally, but my issue was with how to make the lag offset dynamic based on the "last meaningful value".  For example, if I'm at the $2.50 row I need to look back 3 prices to compare against the "last meaningful value" ($1.99).  However, if at the $2.62 row I only need to look back 1 row (for $2.56).  I updated my data set example to correct it, my original values we incorrect given the 20% variance threshold I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION x(prices ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<price FLOAT64, flag STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = [];
  var last = 0;
  var flag = '';
  for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
    if (i == 0) {
      last = prices[i];
      flag = 'Y'
    } else {
      if ((prices[i] - last)/last > 0.02) {
        last = prices[i];
        flag = 'Y'
      } else {flag = 'N'}
    }
    var rec = [];
    rec.price = prices[i];
    rec.flag = flag;
    result.push(rec); 
  } 
  return result;
""";
SELECT item, rec.* 
FROM (
  SELECT item, ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY price) AS prices
  FROM `yourTable`
  GROUP BY item
), UNNEST(x(prices) ) AS rec
-- ORDER BY item, price
```

You can play with / test it with below dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION x(prices ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<price FLOAT64, flag STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = [];
  var last = 0;
  var flag = '';
  for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
    if (i == 0) {
      last = prices[i];
      flag = 'Y'
    } else {
      if ((prices[i] - last)/last > 0.02) {
        last = prices[i];
        flag = 'Y'
      } else {flag = 'N'}
    }
    var rec = [];
    rec.price = prices[i];
    rec.flag = flag;
    result.push(rec); 
  } 
  return result;
""";
WITH `yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 'Apple' AS item, 1.99 AS price UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2.00 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2.01 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2.50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2.56 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2.62 
)
SELECT item, rec.* 
FROM (
  SELECT item, ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY price) AS prices
  FROM `yourTable`
  GROUP BY item
), UNNEST(x(prices) ) AS rec
ORDER BY item, price
```

Result is as below

```sql
item    price   flag     
----    -----   ----
Apple   1.99    Y    
Apple   2.0     N    
Apple   2.01    N    
Apple   2.5     Y    
Apple   2.56    Y    
Apple   2.62    Y
```

Comment: No - haven't tried it just yet, but will shortly; looks like a great use of the UDFs.  Thank you for the thorough reply, let me test it and I'll upvote!

Comment: That worked very well Mikhail, thank you.  I'm really impressed with how the UDF performed; I was always under the impression that they slowed BQ down substantially, but this proved other wise.

Comment: great! glad we did it! meantime, when using JS UDF be aware of potentially rising billing tier as usually JS UDF are quite resource consuming. I think in this particular case you should be good  - but still  - can you check what billing tier you got> just to be on safe side